# Use elements of a convex sets to solve equations

Tags: equation-solving, sets

i try to do sth. like this

```
A=Solve[{x>=5, y>=3, x<13,y<13} ,{x,y}]
```

which gives me a convex set and then

```
Solve[{x==y, y==3}, {x,y}]
```

with (x,y) element of A.

I know that i could just use one solve for all, but for faster computation it would be better if i could calculate A first and then use it for the next step.

How could i do that? 
Thank you very much

Comment: Your Solve syntax doesn't seem correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much benefit to doing this in multiple steps, but if you want to do it that way I would suggest solving these equations with `Reduce` and combinations of `And`:

```
equation1 = And[x >= 5, y >= 3, x < 13, y < 13];
equation2 = And[x==y,y==3];
Reduce[ And[ equation1, equation2 ], {x,y} ]
```

which gives `False` because the second equation leads to `x` and `y` both being 3:

```
Reduce[And[x == y, y == 3], {x, y}] (* gives x == 3 && y == 3 *)
```

And that falls outside of the region defined by the first equation:

```
RegionPlot[ And[x >= 5, y >= 3, x < 13, y < 13], {x, 0, 15}, {y, 0, 15}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thx Arnoud, i just tried to create a fast example code so that my problem is clear. If i get you r code right than still all the calculation is done in the "Reduce" line, right. So that if i have a do slop over 15k equations the convex room needs to be calculated everytime?

Comment: I think so. It would be *extremely* useful if you edit your original question so it includes correct Wolfram Language code in the first place (people tend to vote to close questions otherwise) and also a full problem description (you did not mention the 15K equations before, so my answer did not take this into account. The more effort you put into asking a clear question, the more likely you are going to get a great answer!